# How to merge partial properties with the default values of a type and return instance of type

Tags: typescript

How do I write a merge function that takes a partial of a type and a default instance of a type, and merges properties of partial object and default object, and returns an instance of the type.

```
function merge<A>(pa: Partial<A>, da: A): A {
    // merge properties from pa, or use da
    return da;
}

type Piece = {
    color: string,
    rank: string
}

const defaultPiece: Piece = {
    color: 'w',
    rank: '1'
}

const partialPiece: Partial<Piece> = {
    color: 'b'
}

console.log(merge(partialPiece, defaultPiece));

// logs { color: 'b', rank: '1' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or the spread syntax:

```
function merge<A>(pa: Partial<A>, da: A): A {
    return Object.assign({}, da, pa);
    // or
    return {...da, ...pa};
}
```

Typescript should infer the returned type as `A & Partial<A>` so it's not strictly necessary to provide one. Be aware of mutating references when merging objects like this. Both methods above will clone `da` and `pa` respectively to one level of depth.